# Unable to add Sub-Folders using CSOM

Tags: development, csom

I have the following code to create a root folder and sub-folders inside my remote event receiver:-

```
foreach (ListItem i2 in collListItem2)
                        {
var templatenumber = isDeal ? "10" : i2["TemplateNumber"];
CamlQuery camlQuery3 = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery3.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Templates' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", templatenumber);
ListItemCollection collListItem3 = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl + "/lists/" + "Levels").GetItems(camlQuery3);
context.Load(collListItem3, items => items.Include(
                                item => item.Id,
                                item => item["Level0"],
                                item => item["Level1"],
                                item => item["Level2"],
                                item => item["Level3"],
                                item => item["Level4"],
                                item => item["Level5"]
                                ));
context.ExecuteQuery();
List templatelsit = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl + "/" + i2["TemplateListUrl"]);
//create the Main Folder

ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();

// Below are options.
// (1) File - This will create a file in the list or document library
// (2) Folder - This will create a foder in list(if folder creation is enabled) or documnt library
listItemCreationInformation.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
listItemCreationInformation.LeafName = i["EntityName"].ToString();
ListItem listItem = templatelsit.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
listItem["Title"] = i["EntityName"];
listItem.Update();
ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation2 = new ListItemCreationInformation();

// create sub-folder
                               listItemCreationInformation2.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;

// This will et the internal name/path of the file/folder
listItemCreationInformation2.LeafName = i["EntityName"].ToString() + "/" + i3["Level1"].ToString();

    try
       {
         ListItem listItem2 = templatelsit.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation2);
         listItem2.Update();
       }
         catch { }
```

now the above code will add the main folder, but will not add the sub-folder. so can anyone advice on this please?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the below code, I have added `context.ExecuteQuery();` in the required places.

```
foreach (ListItem i2 in collListItem2)
{
var templatenumber = isDeal ? "10" : i2["TemplateNumber"];
CamlQuery camlQuery3 = new CamlQuery();
camlQuery3.ViewXml = string.Format("<View Scope=\"RecursiveAll\"><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Templates' /><Value Type='Text'>{0}</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>", templatenumber);
ListItemCollection collListItem3 = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl + "/lists/" + "Levels").GetItems(camlQuery3);
context.Load(collListItem3, items => items.Include(
                                item => item.Id,
                                item => item["Level0"],
                                item => item["Level1"],
                                item => item["Level2"],
                                item => item["Level3"],
                                item => item["Level4"],
                                item => item["Level5"]
                                ));
context.ExecuteQuery();
List templatelsit = context.Web.GetList(webrelativeurl + "/" + i2["TemplateListUrl"]);
//create the Main Folder

ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation = new ListItemCreationInformation();

// Below are options.
// (1) File - This will create a file in the list or document library
// (2) Folder - This will create a foder in list(if folder creation is enabled) or documnt library
listItemCreationInformation.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;
listItemCreationInformation.LeafName = i["EntityName"].ToString();
ListItem listItem = templatelsit.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation);
listItem["Title"] = i["EntityName"];
listItem.Update();
context.ExecuteQuery(); // now the folder would have been created

ListItemCreationInformation listItemCreationInformation2 = new ListItemCreationInformation();

// create sub-folder
listItemCreationInformation2.UnderlyingObjectType = FileSystemObjectType.Folder;

// This will et the internal name/path of the file/folder
listItemCreationInformation2.LeafName = i["EntityName"].ToString() + "/" + i3["Level1"].ToString();

    try
       {
         ListItem listItem2 = templatelsit.AddItem(listItemCreationInformation2);
         listItem2.Update();
         context.ExecuteQuery(); // now the sub folder would have been created
       }
         catch { }
```

Comment: ok worked well...